# Performance or utilization of GPU on Windows 10

Tags: windows, tensorflow, gpu

I have two problems regarding to performance of GPU on Windows 10:

1. Poor GPU utilization
2. Can't increase the batch size beyond 2048

Here is the system configuration:

- GPU: 2080 ti
- CUDA: 10.0
- cuDNN: v7.4.2.24
- Python: 3.6.5
- TensorFlow: 1.13.1

**For Issue #1**: the training speed on win10 (4% utiliztion) is 4-5 slower than that for a 2080 ti on Linux (90%).  This is not a memory problem: both systems have sufficient memory for the entire dataset.

**For Issue #2**: training is ok with batch size of 2048. It does not work with the batch size of 4096.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you try with `gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.9)` and then

`with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options)) as sess:`

Comment: I am using Keras.  How can I do that in Keras.  Many thanks.

Comment: I found an question "use tensorflow.GPUOptions within Keras when using tensorflow backend" and will try to implement.  Thanks.

Comment: The gpu_options does not work - the utilization is the same.